# How can I be as anonymous as possible while on Tor?

Tags: anonymity, tor

I've started browsing the deep web recently and have seen a lot of illegal content. Now while I have no interest in any of the illegal content, I don't want to be caught on one of these sights because of a misclick, clicking on a misleading link, or clicking on an unknown link and get in trouble. Plus I guess I would feel safer being anonymous.

Comment: Read the guide that should be on the first page of Tor about changing your habits also think about using tails

Comment: Also take a look at this article on it, http://lifehacker.com/how-can-i-stay-anonymous-with-tor-1498876762 but this is very extreme

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternate identity. Browse on TOR using a public connection and computer that is wholly separate from your home network. A VPN to hide your location might be a good idea as well.

Do not mix your identities in any way shape or form.

That will give you the most anonymity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a good idea to use special linux distributions like
[Tails](https://tails.boum.org/index.en.html)

> Tails is a live operating system, that you can start on almost any computer from a DVD, USB stick, or SD card. It aims at preserving your privacy and anonymity.

or [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Main_Page)

> Whonix is an operating system focused on anonymity, privacy and security. It's based on the Tor anonymity network, Debian GNU/Linux and security by isolation. DNS leaks are impossible, and not even malware with root privileges can find out the user's real IP.